Django Channels on IIS using FASTCGI
I am deploying a Django app using an IIS server. In this Django app, I have implemented Django Channels to use websockets. Locally, everything is working fine with websocket connections, and I am able to send messages. However, the issue arises when I deploy the Django app. The HTTPS works perfectly fine, but the WSS (WebSocket Secure) is not working. I encounter a 404 not found error.
the url in which I am trying is
wss://my_domain/ws/start-quiz/

also note that i am using memurai instead of redis to use channel_layers
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
            'CONFIG': {
                "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6370)],
            },
        },
    }


I had same issue, I solved this using Daphne with channels.
my web.config file conatins
rules>
   <rule name="WebSocketProxy" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^ws/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:8001/ws/{R:1}" />
   </rule>
</rules>

and to run Daphne on local I used following command
daphne -p 8000 your_project_name.asgi:application

Please make sure first your Django project configuration using IIS with FASTCGI is correct

Thank you for answer, I tried this and it is working for me...
